# Accessing Connected Database DB in Eclipse with Java Code

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, database-connection

I successfully connected to a DB in eclipse through the Database Development perspective and am able to run queries in the SQL File Editor. However, I would like to write java code to automatically run a query and then extract the data to a flat file. What is the easiest way to do this? Since I am already connected to the database, can I bypass the java code that involves connecting to the database.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Java JVM also needs to be able to connect to the database. There are many examples of JDBC connections on the internet, including [this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm).

Once you have got the data you needed, you should make use of [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) in order to write the information to file.